# LINQ - a part of string is contained in a list elements

Tags: list, linq, contains

I have a database with a column can contain value separated by commas, as:

```
madrid, barcelona, paris
rome
paris
amsterdam, madrid
florence, tokyo
paris, barcelona
milan
london, edinburgh
....
```

Then I have a List as:

```
var listTarget = new List<string>{"paris", "amsterdam", "rome"};
```

In LINQ I want extract all rows that contain at least a value in listTarget, so the result will be:

```
madrid, barcelona, paris
rome
paris
amsterdam, madrid
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you please share your attempted code ?

Comment: I use this WHERE clause but I get error:     Where(a => listTarget.Any(e => a.city.Contains(e)))

Comment: What error ur getting.

Answer (score 1):

You could split using delimiter (in this case ',') and compare the lists. For example,

```
.Where(x=> x.City.Split(',').Any(c=> listTarget.Contains(c.Trim())));
```

Comment: I get this error: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: @Alfra I have updated the answer. Could you please verify

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my vb.net linq but you can convert it to C#. What I have used is a combination of linq and regex to get the accurate result check out this code

```
DT.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(n) system.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch((cstr(n("A"))),string.Join("|",List_of_strr) )).CopyToDataTable
```

And I also used a datatable here as I didn't have a database. The `"A"` in `cstr(n("A")` is the column name.